# Overview of integrating OAuth 2.0 with a Custom API (written in Laravel)

Tags: php, android, api, oauth, laravel

I created an Android App that communicates with an API I set up using PHP and am going to attempt to rewrite the PHP stuff using Laravel. One of the big changes I want to make is to allow OAuth login into my app that is associated with a user account on my local servers and I am confused about the application flow involved to do this.

Should I do my OAuth authentication on my Android app before registering, then store some sort of credential along with user information when I call my API to create my local user account?

Also, when logging a user in using OAuth, how do I know that the person who is authenticated by the provider, say Facebook, Is associated with a local user account on my servers? Is there some sort of token I can store?

Thanks for any overview information you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did the same (without OAuth provider from my site) with [HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/) There is also a [composer package at packagist.org](https://packagist.org/packages/hybridauth/hybridauth).

I have two tables for that:

- **users** with columns id, email, password (table with my normal users and user infos)
- **authentications** with columns: id, user_id, provider, provider_uid (authentication table with the stuff for OAuth.)

The Code I have in my AuthController (for the route /login/social `Route::controller('login','AuthController');`)

```
<?php

class AuthController extends BaseController {

    //@see http://www.mrcasual.com/on/coding/laravel4-package-management-with-composer/
    public function getSocial($action = '')
    {
        // check URL segment
        if ($action == 'auth') {
            // process authentication
            try {
                Hybrid_Endpoint::process();
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                // redirect back to http://URL/social/
                return Redirect::to('login/social');
            }
            return;
        }
        try {
            // create a HybridAuth object
            $socialAuth = new Hybrid_Auth(app_path() . '/config/hybridauth.php');
            // authenticate with provider
            if($action != ''){
                // only allow facebook and google
                if(in_array($action,array('google','facebook'))){
                    $provider = $socialAuth->authenticate($action);
                }else{
                    // catch this form_error in the login form
                    return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors(array('form_errors'=>'The url was invalid'));
                }
            }else{
                return Redirect::to('login');
            }
            // fetch user profile
            $userProfile = $provider->getUserProfile();
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            // exception codes can be found on HybBridAuth's web site
            return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors(array('form_errors'=>'Error on Login: #'.$e->getCode().': '.$e->getMessage()));
        }
        /*access user profile data
        echo "Connected with: <b>{$provider->id}</b><br />";
        echo "As: <b>{$userProfile->displayName}</b><br />";
        echo "<pre>" . print_r( $userProfile, true ) . "</pre><br />";
        die();*/


        //check if User exists
        if($user_id = DB::table('authentications')->where('provider', $provider->id)->where('provider_uid',$userProfile->identifier)->pluck('user_id')){
            //login user
            Auth::loginUsingId($user_id);
            //update user details (eg photo, name, etc)
            //Here you can update the user details
            return Redirect::to('dashboard');
        }else{
            //lets see if we already know this email -> connect it with the registered account
            if($user = User::where('email',$userProfile->email)->first()){
                $user->authentications()->save(new Authentication(array('provider'=>$provider->id, 'provider_uid'=>$userProfile->identifier)));
                Auth::login($user);
                //here you can update the user details 
                return Redirect::to('dashboard')->with('user_social_linked',$provider->id);
            }else{
                //register user
                $user = $this->createUser(array('email'=>$userProfile->email,'password'=>''));
                $user->authentications()->save(new Authentication(array('provider'=>$provider->id, 'provider_uid'=>$userProfile->identifier)));
                Auth::login($user);
                //here you can set/update the user details 
                return Redirect::to('dashboard')->with('user_created',true);
            }
        }
    }

    private function createUser($credentials)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->email = $credentials['email'];
        $user->password = $credentials['password'];
        $user->save();
        Auth::login($user);
        return $user;
    }
}
```

The User model has also the following function

```
<?php
public function setPasswordAttribute($password){
    //disable blank passwords => disables account login (eg login only with third party aka social providers)
    if($password != ''){
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($password);
    }else{
        $this->attributes['password'] = $password;
    }
}
```

Now you can treat your own OAuth provider just as any other OAuth provider, eg by adding / configuring a hybridauth provider.

To your questions:

> Should I do my OAuth authentication on my Android app before registering, then store some sort of credential along with user information when I call my API to create my local user account?

I would handle it the same as with any other OAuth provider: like in the example above one function to call (I only use login via the Laravel Auth, so I do not have the issues with expiring provider sessions and the user does not have to create another account).

> Also, when logging a user in using OAuth, how do I know that the person who is authenticated by the provider, say Facebook, Is associated with a local user account on my servers? Is there some sort of token I can store?

This is done by the user_id column in the authentications table.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Extremely helpful. Reading over the OAuth2 spec and having this has me on my way. Thank you!

Comment: One remark: If a user creates an account and afterwards tries to login with a (not linked) social provider you may end up with multiple accounts if the user uses different email addresses (like disposable emails).